# Read image and set texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, renderer, texture2d

I add a cube to unity scene. I want to set this cub's texture by using an image.

I use below code to load image and set texture :

```
Texture2D text2D = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height,TextureFormat.RGB24 , false);
text2D.SetPixels(((Texture2D)Resources.Load("image")).GetPixels());
MeshRenderer renderer = cube.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

renderer.material.mainTexture = text2D;
```

I see only a gray cube not the image on the scene.

Comment: [have you read through the documentation of SetPixels()?](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten this quite a bit with only:

```
renderer.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("image");
```

Note that if the image is not found then you get null.

Answer (score 1):

To see changes on the `Texture2D`, use `text2d.Apply();`

Answer (score 1):

This is even more easy to do.

Try

```
public GameObject _cube;

void Start()
{
    Renderer rend = _cube.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    rend.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load ("image") as Texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LoadImage method can also be used to do the job. But here, you have to pass in the image as .bytes format.
Example:

```
    public TextAsset image;
    void Start()
    {
        var texture = new Texture2D(100, 100, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        texture.LoadImage(image.bytes);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
        texture.Apply();
    }
```